# Proof with area segments in a triangle

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

[image]

> I have to show that $A M_CS$ and $M_CBS$ have the same area $X$ and that concerning areas $X=Y=Z$ is true.

I'm really stuck here, I would appreciate any help or tip...! How can I start here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $M_C$ is the midpoint of $AB$, then $A M_CS$ and $M_CBS$ have equal bases and share the same height.

Can you proceed for the first part?

For the second part, a similar approach, except consider the triangles $CM_CB$ and $CM_CA$. Are these areas equal? Express each of the areas in terms of $X, Y$ and $Z$.

Can you finish up for the second part?

Comment: In fact, this can be used to easily derive the result that the centroid divides the vertex-midpoint line segments $2:1$. Pretty cool. More elementary than the usual proof using vectors that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thank you so much for your perfect tip, which helped a lot! I came up with this – is this sufficient?  1. $AM_CS = M_CBS :=X \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} \cdot AM_C \cdot h_{ABS} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot M_CB \cdot h_{ABS} \Longleftrightarrow AM_C = M_CB \checkmark \because A + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \vec{AB\,} = M_C.$ and 2. Analogous to 1. you can show that $Y:=ASM_B=M_BSC$ and $Z := SM_AC = BM_AS $ and $AM_CC = M_CBC \,(= X+Z+Z = X+Y+Y)$ and $BAM_A = M_AAC \,(= Y+X+X = Y+Z+Z)$. And because $AM_CC = BAM_A$ it is $X+Z+Z = X+Y+Y = Y+X+X = Y+Z+Z$ and therefore $X+Y+Z$.